# What is a nanocomputer processing node?

Tags: internal-consistency, computers, nanotechnology

I came across this future science term and I need to know what it is and what it does. Here's a link to it in the book I found.

https://books.google.com/books?id=luCFTmzpZIkC&pg=PA205&lpg=PA205&dq=nanocomputing+processor+node&source=bl&ots=K_p0jhda_V&sig=aTajnJBqad0SPXHdNiCN5NfuNgw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi05sP6qefWAhUD4IMKHe4SABEQ6AEIJzAB#v=onepage&q=nanocomputing%20processor%20node&f=false

Comment: Reality check for what time exactly? The transistor length scale today for the [7nm node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7_nanometer) is about ~50nm.

Comment: Far future I assume. I have NO idea what it means

Comment: I'm not sure this has an answer.  Even in the context of that book, "nanocomputer processing node" is highly handwaved.  Without specifics about what it does or how small it is, we can't answer this.

Comment: This question isn't about building a fictional world. As such it is a bad fit for this site and should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially it is part of an advanced type of computer based on nanotechnology. Below is a description of aspects of a nanocomputer. Current computers based on the Von Neumann architecture. This discusses computers beyond Von Neumann machines.

In a science-fiction story that phrase is there to give the reader a sense of advanced technology. Don't worry, there won't be a test afterwards.

[image: Nanocomputer architecture]

Source: Richard C Dorf (ed) *The Engineering Handbook, Second Edition* (CRC press, 2002)

Comment: There seems to be an implicit, but unsupported, assumption that computers "beyond" the von Neuman architecture are both possible and generally useful.  And for a practical example, consider one of the possibly upwards of 1024 compute cores in an NVida "graphics" card.

Comment: @jamesqf Assumptions are like that. Unfortunately, I'm not a techhead, so your practical example sounds fascinating but means little to me. Others more knowledgeable will understand precisely your point. Although life is full of gadgets where newer doesn't mean better or more reliable.